# How to overwrite file in Java with one changed value

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make a program that uses JFrames and JPanels to construct a voting program.  There is a file called voters.txt that is formatted like so:

```
1234:Herb Weaselman:false
9876:Marge Magnificent:false
4444:Ingmar Inglenook:false
8888:Hector Heroman:false
5678:Agnes Angular:false
```

In the beginning of my program, I have to ask the user for their voter ID and if their input does not match one of the IDs from the text file, then the program ends.  I have managed to achieve this but now I need to overwrite this voters.txt file by changing the false element of whoever voted to true.  For instance, if the user entered an ID of 1234, then I would need to change the word after Herb Weaselman to true instead of false.  I am not sure how to do this.  I know how to write to a file but am not sure how to change that one specific element.  Here is the code I have currently:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Assig5 extends JFrame
{

    public Assig5()
    {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        LoginWindow loginWindow = new LoginWindow();
        loginWindow.fileReader();
        if(!loginWindow.checkResult(loginWindow.result))
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Voter ID");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Continue");

    }
}

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LoginWindow extends JFrame
  {
    static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    public String result;
    public LoginWindow()
    {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter voter ID:");

    }
    public static void fileReader() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("voters.txt"));
        while (s.hasNextLine())
        {
          list.add(s.nextLine());
        }
        s.close();
    }
    public static boolean checkResult(String result)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
          String[] retval = list.get(i).split(":");
          if(retval[0].equals(result))
          {
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
    }
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to create a POJO which represented each row in the text file, read the entire text file in when the program starts.  Update the values of the POJO as needed and save these back to the file as needed

Comment: ^ what he said. You should be doing logical operations objects instead of  text files, but if you really wanted to you can do a regex string replacement as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your array index from `false` to `true` when there is a match. Then rewrite the file with the data from the array. If there is not match, the file does not change.

---

### Solution

```
if(retval[0].equals(result)){
    retval[2] = true;
    return true;
}
```